# $_POST superglobal does not contain the expected data after an HTML form submission

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
<?PHP
$username = $_POST['username'];
print ($username);
?>
</head>
<body>

<form name ="form1" method ="POST" action = "allNewPractice.php">
<input type = "text" value ="username">
<input type = "submit" name = "submit1" value = "login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The name of this file, as you can probably tell, is "allNewPractice.php" and I use
 localhost/allNewPractice.php directly through my browser to access it, not through notepad++'s  run.
it doesn't work whatsoever; its supposed to print the information I typed into the text box to the page but The page does NOTHING.When I click the login button the page only refreshes, shows the original text box and the login button, but doesn't show what i entered.
I got the tutorial from http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p6.html 
what am i doing wrong?
Is there something wrong with my computer?

Comment: Try `<?php` instead of `<?PHP`.  Also, verify that if you view the HTML source of the page, you also don't see your PHP... that would imply your PHP isn't getting parsed.  Use your browser's developer tools to verify that a POST is actually occurring.

Comment: Did you check developer tools for errors?

Comment: i really don't understand what you are saying about the server part,even thoug I have a basic idea of what servers are. But I do have mySQl and Apache installed. infact they're running right now, and i can see the green light on the apache and mySQL icons

Comment: i even change the <?PHP to a lowercase one. still not working.

Comment: What they're trying to say is that you have to check your HTML via the Inspector of your browser. If you use chrome simply do right clic and then "Inspect element" You'll see a small window down the screen.

Comment: what happens when you type the word 'localhost' into the address bar of your browser and press enter?  Do you see a webpage, or do you get an error?

Comment: dudeeeeeeeeee it totally workeddddd lol. Thanks man. i think it was the website's fault cause that totally worked

Comment: This is **not** the place to be if you do not understand the fundamentals of writing a computer program to be interactive on the internet. This place is for people who are having 'issues' with their programs. You need to decide which situation you have. There are other sites that are **much** better suited to learning to do that.

Comment: it was a simple mistake calm down. I'm not good at web programming and i had been coding for hours now, this was just a separate practice page.this happens to EVERYONE.

Comment: @RyanVincent Questions like this one are completely appropriate and on-topic for Stack Overflow.  It's clear, concise, and has a minimal example of code to reproduce the problem.  My only problem with this question is the way the title is worded, which I am going to edit for him now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn basic HTML forms:

```
<input type = "text" value ="username">
```

Inputs with no name do not submit anything. It should be

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="somevalue" />
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----must be present.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a `name` attribute to the input box, as such:

```
<input type = "text" value ="username" name="username">
```

When you call `$_POST['username']`, it is referencing the name attribute, not the value.

Second, you are setting the value of `$username` before anything has been posted. This will result in an error, `undefined variable: username`, because `$_POST['username']` does not exist when you first load the page. Not until after you submit the form will it have a value. So, you need to check if the form has been submitted first:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    // Process data from form
}
```

Here is a complete and working version of your program:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        print ($username);
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name ="form1" method ="POST" action = "allNewPractice.php">
            <input type = "text" value ="username" name="username">
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit1" value = "login">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. personally i just dont seem to use the post method but it works

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>   

<?PHP
if ($_GET['username']) {
$user = $_GET['username'];
echo $user;
}else{
echo "no text";
}
?>
</head>
<body>

<form method ="GET" action = "allNewPractice.php">
<input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
<input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "login">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```